# Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for:ComponentInfo(XXX)

Tags: android, instrumentation

When i use Espresso to test Android UI, I followed by https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html,but it cannot work for me, and when I run the test, caused this error! But the android-testing samples (espresso/BasicSample)work's ok, when i change the applicationId, it doesn't work,
also caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation setup android UI test with Espresso: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

This is my problem, I typed "Runner" to "Ruuner"...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tmkc.jpg)